# How to stop shakey animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have an animation [here](https://4309.co.uk/in-addition)

The problem is that it's quite shakey and not smooth as it should be. In addition its pushing my footer down and up with each cycle.

Is there a way of making it seamless?

All of my text animations are shakey, even on my [front page](https://4309.co.uk) in mobile. Is there some kind of rule here that I'm missing? Is box-shadow or text shadow an issue with animations or does transforming text from one size to another or one state to another usually cause it? Can I use transform:scale somehow here and would it fix the issue?

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

.sometext {
  color: #787878;
  font-size: 30px;
  text- shadow: -2px -3px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75), 2px 4px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-align: center;
}

.sometext {
  animation: text-color 10s linear infinite;
  position: relative;
  animation. direction: alternate. reverse;
}

@keyframes text-color {
  0% {
    text-shadow: -2px -3px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75), 2px 4px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  }
  50% {
    text-shadow: 10px 10px 30px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75), 30px 20px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  }
  100% {
    text-shadow: 10px 10px 30px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75), 30px 20px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  }
}

.white {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 10px 30px 30px 40px white;
  width: 20px;
  left: -1px;
  top: -110 px;
  opacity: 0.1
}

.white {
  animation: torch 10s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  position: relative;
  animation. direction: alternate. reverse;
}

@keyframes torch {
  from {
    background-color: grey;
  }
  to {
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 10px 30px 30px 40px white;
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
}

.sunray {
  height: 200px;
  width: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: blur(5px);
  position: relative;
  left: 110px;
  top: -120px;
}

.sunray {
  animation: ray 15s linear infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

@keyframes ray {
  from {
    transform: translate(-100px, -50px) rotate(-45deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    color: transparent;
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
}

.sunray1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: blur(5px);
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  top: -250px;
}

.sunray1 {
  animation: ray1 10s linear infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

@keyframes ray1 {
  from {
    height: 2px;
  }
  to {
    height: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sometext">text text text text text text text text text. </div>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="sunray"></div>
<div class="sunray1"></div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update with relevant code to a [mcve]

Comment: I think the real problem is subpixel animation doesn't really work too well on a lot of browsers. What you're seeing is "pixel snapping", the only real solution is a faster animation where this isn't noticeable. At this point, you may want to consider a 2d graphics library like PIXI.JS for what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks. Yes it's interesting that example given seems to work better on Chrome mobile then desktop....can I use transform: scale somehow? I understand I may be able to apply it to front page but not sure how to apply it to text shadow https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale

Comment: You could also try to make a much larger canvas and then scaling it down with CSS, essentially creating a higher DPI. This should at least look better on devices with higher device pixel ratio. Note that animating heavy blurs and glows might also get choppy because of rendering time, perhaps using WebGL will make this faster.

Comment: @Kokodoko sorry but if I used `<canvas>` and JavaScript, could I produce pretty much the same thing but without jerky effect? How would I create this large canvas and how would I scale it down? I'm unfamiliar with `<canvas>` element and JS..

Comment: I didn't test this but I believe you can say `<canvas id="mycanvas" width="4000" height="3000"></canvas>` and scale it down with CSS : `#mycanvas { width: 2000px; height:1500px;}`